# How do I find replacement parts for my 1988 Suntour drive train?

Tags: compatibility, parts, drivetrain

I am resurrecting my old commuter which was basically a hard-tail MTB c 1988 with a 3 x 7 Suntour system.  What's the least painful method (leaving shifters and derailleur intact) to replace the worn chain ring and cassette?

I want to use new parts, and I'm fine with the old fashion setup.  I'm not seeing new Suntour sets for sale, however, and my research on this site hasn't helped me find any encouraging information.

Comment: Is it a cassette or freewheel?

Comment: Nathan--We've solved that part of the situation with a freewheel from Interloc.  Thank you for the correction on what I was dealing with. The bb is fine, as far as I can tell, but has about 20k miles on it. The chainrings will be easy enough for sizing. Looks like I'm getting my old bike back!

Answer (score 1):

The chainrings are likely easy; the vast majority of such bikes had standard non-ramped chainrings in the 110/74 BCD, or potentially another standard size. Typically any non-ramped repair/replacement chainrings of the same tooth counts will work. If the goal is just put on a functional drivetrain and not so much save the old cranks per se, putting on a new basic crank and its needed BB often comes out cheaper, especially if the original BB needs replacing anyway.

The cassette is stickier, if it is a cassette. Suntour cassettes are long out of production and Suntour cassette hubs have no compatibility with anything else. The option is buy a vintage one from eBay etc or replace the wheel/hub. If it's a freewheel, anything with matching tooth counts or close will do.

Replace the chain along with the other drivetrain parts always.

Comment: I have a dedicated wet-day bike with 7 speed cassette.  I source them from Aliexpress for under $20 each, because no local bike shop has ever had them.

Comment: @Criggie It's not the 7-speed-ness, it's the Suntour. Suntour cassette hubs are their own cassette standard completely.